# Running aggregate function on Django queryset union with renamed fields raises django.db.utils.DatabaseError

Tags: django, django-queryset, union

I am using Django 3.2

I am trying to create a query that queries two different models and does the following:

- renames the returned columns (so the queries can be 'union'ed together
- 'unions' the two querysets (after column rename using `annotate`)
- tries to run an aggregate function `Sum` on the union (this is where it barfs).

This is a simplified version of my codebase:

#### Models

```
class EventCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    category = models.ForeignKey(EventCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    category = models.ForeignKey(EventCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prize_money = models.IntegerField()



class TournamentAward(models.Model):
    awardee =  models.ForeignKey(setting.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)



class Game(models.Model):
    player =  models.ForeignKey(setting.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment = models.SmallPositiveInteger()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

#### Queries

```
payment_earned_today = Game.objects.filter(
                                          player=user,
                                          created_at__year=year, 
                                          created_at__month=month, 
                                          created_at__day=day
                                            ).annotate(category=models.F('event__category'))\
                                       .only('category','payment')
        
        
  
  tournament_prize_today = TournamentAward.objects.filter(
                                          awardee=user,
                                          created_at__year=year, 
                                          created_at__month=month, 
                                          created_at__day=day
                                      ).select_related('tournament__category')\                                            
                              .annotate(category=models.F('tournament__category'))\                                           
                              .annotate(payment=models.F('tournament__prize_money'))\
                              .only('category','payment')


# Union the two querysets ...
union_queryset = payment_earned_today.union( tournament_prize_today )
results = union_queryset.aggregate(total=models.Sum('payment'))
```

On the line when I try to calculate the total, I get the following error:

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements

How can I union two models and calculate an aggregate function on the union?

Answer (score 0):

at first:

you don't need to rename fields.

```
filter_query = Q(created_at__year=year,created_at__month=month,created_at__day=day)
payment_earned_today = Game.objects.filter(player=user, filter_query).values('event__category'. 'payment')
```

at second:

you can set `order_by` before aggregate.

```
queryset.query.order_by=None
```

at third:

Why you don't go from `category`?

```
event_query = Q(event__game__created_at__year=year, event__game__created_at__month=month, event__game__created_at__day=day, event__game__player=user)

tournament_query = Q(tournament__tournamentaward__created_at__year=year, tournament__tournamentaward__created_at__month=month, tournament__tournamentaward__created_at__day=day, tournament__tournamentaward__awardee=user)

all_category = EventCategory.ojects.filter(event_query | tournament_query)
```

I don't understand if is an error in your last core row or not:
`results` is plural, but you have `aggregate(sum)`, it give you only one result. Therefore:

```
all_category_with_summ_in_day_for_user = all_category.annotate(Sum('tournament__prize_money'), Sum('event__game__payment'))

# or

summs_for_all_category_in_day_for_user= all_category.aggregate(Sum('tournament__prize_money'), Sum('event__game__payment'))
```